# wp_redirect shows header already sent message

Tags: wp-redirect

I am new to wordpress plugin development. I have created a list page and an add item page. When I add successfully, I want to redirect and it is giving me this error.

[image]

**Notice the error is on `pluggable.php on line 876`**

I have checked many sources but unable to find the solution so far

1. I have used `wp_redirect('admin.php?page=ccURLList'); exit;` it gives the attached error
2. I have used `no-header` in the query string of form submission, it does work but in case of any error I wanted to show the page again and that page is without any sidebar or wp stuff
3. When i move the `wp_redirect` to my main file `clickCounter.php` it says function is unknown

If any of you can resolve this issue, it will be highly appreciated.

**EDIT**

`clickCounter.php` is my main file. It creates menus etc.

I have a list page which is working.

I have an add page. I have put the wp_redirect on the very first lines after

```
<?php
// ccURLAdd.php my add page
if (!defined('ABSPATH'))
    die('You are not allowed to call this page directly.');

add_action( 'init', 'CCaddNewLink' );
function CCaddNewLink(){
    wp_redirect(home_url());
    exit;
}
//wp_redirect('admin.php?page=click-counter');
exit;
```

Below is my main file

```
<?php
// clickCounter.php my main page.
/* some plugin info */
add_action('admin_menu', 'ccAdminMenu');
function ccAdminMenu()
{
    add_menu_page("Click Counter", "Click Counter", 8, 'click-counter', "ccAdminMenuListUrls", CC_HTML_WEB . "/images/icon.png");
    add_submenu_page('click-counter', 'Add New Link', 'Add Link', 8, 'click-counter-url-new', 'ccAdminAddUrl');

}
function ccAdminAddUrl()
{
    include 'ccURLAdd.php';
}
```

Comment: *where* do you call wp_redirect? this is not unique to WordPress, you can't send a redirect header after content has already been sent to the browser.

Comment: You are trying to redirect after content has been sent to the browser. This can be intentional content or unintentional, such as `echo`ed `Notice`s. You will need to post your code.

Comment: i have updated my question

Comment: [same question/answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/100368/4771)

Comment: @Milo I tried that nothing happened

Comment: Your `ccAdminAddUrl()` function should render the page that the user will see so they can perform whatever actions you want them to do. At this stage all you are doing is trying to redirect someone when they click on the sub-menu-page to another page, when the sub-menu-page is the actual page you want in the first place... Also you can't embed an action in a function that is called by `admin_menu` which will render the function after the headers are already sent which is why the redirect does not work. Your `init` hook must execute before your `admin_menu` hook.

Comment: @userabuser well my page renders, i just made this code to clean the space. I'll check the hook thing out of function

Comment: @userabuser ahh, yes it worked... hmm so if I have like 20 sections in my plugin and each have to redirect to different url. I have to create 20 functions outside the class etc...