# How to send "Location" header on plugin form submit event?

Tags: plugins, php, redirect, headers

How to redirect to specified page after form was submitted?

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at `wordpress\wp-admin\menu-header.php:94`) in
>   `wordpress\wp-content\plugins\test\test.php` on line 16

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: TEST
Plugin URI: http://localhost/
Description: TEST
Version: 0.0.1
Author: TEST
Author URI: http://localhost/
*/
add_action('admin_menu', 'test');
function test() { 
    add_menu_page('test', 'test', 0, 'test/test.php', 'page');
} 
function page() {
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        header('Location: /index.php');
        exit;
    }
    echo '<form action="" method="post"><input type="submit" value="Submit form" name="submit" /></form>';
    var_dump($_POST);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to send a redirect header on the `admin_menu` action, which is fired after some of the page has been sent to the browser. You have to hook an earlier action before output starts, like `init`.

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpa_test' );
function wpa_test() {
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        exit;
    }
}
```